# Can my neighbor post signs on my side of the fence?

Tags: canada, real-estate, alberta

This is about a friend and not myself.  The situation takes place in Alberta Canada.

A friend of mine moved into his new home and the next-door neighbor demanded he pay for half the fence (Which was already existing) that separated their property.  My friend obviously declined such an obnoxious demand.

This caused somewhat of a feud between them which im my opinion certainly constitutes harassment, however the latest act was that the neighbor has reached over the fence to install a custom made "private property" sign that says:

"NO USE OF FENCE; no attaching, climbing, pushing, pulling, leaning or bouncing of objects.  NOT A BOUNDARY LINE"

The neighbor did pay for the fence and it is (supposedly) on his property, but it  feels questionably legal for him to be reaching into my friends property to post signs like this.

Is it legal?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

It is not legally reaching into a person's property if you post a sign on your property that can be seem from the person's property. If the fence is physically on / over your friend's property, the fence is encroaching and would be removable by legal means: a sign on the fence would encroach just as much as the fence does. Your friend can legally construct a fence on a portion of his property than makes the offending fence invisible; or your friend could ignore the sign.

Comment: Assuming, of course, that the neighbor (or friend, in your hypothetical second fence scenario) has followed local laws and regulations in the construction, such as receiving appropriate permits. Some jurisdictions only require permits for fences over a certain height, depending on various other factors, while others may require permits for any fence.

Answer (score -2):

I am not there so I don't know who's side the fence got put up on, but:

1. If the fence is on your friend's property he can file a trespassing suit and have it removed if he wants.
2. If the fence, or half of it lol, is your friend's and he does not like the sign, take it down and be done.